# Jquery attribute name filtering + Video-JS

Tags: jquery, html5-video, playback

Can you use Jquery attribute name filtering to select all Video-JS videos on a page and pausing them?

i'm using this to select all id's ending on _panel_movie_m4v and pausing them:

```
    $('[id$=_panel_movie_m4v]')[0].pause();
```

But it won't work. if i use the full selector however, everything works fine...

```
    $("#world_map_8_panel_movie_m4v")[0].pause();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('[id$="_panel_movie_m4v"]')[0].pause();
```

It's looks like id's generated by asp.net. If you have full control over generated html (for example is generated  using repeater) I suggest to create dedicated attributes or adding specific css class for items you would like to select.